# how to respond to multitouch of android in java

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, multi-touch

i'm currently work an android app that have gamepad/game's controller function with client-server system, where the client is android and the server is java desktop application in PC and bluetooth as the connection. this far, my application is work with only 1 finger (hold or click) and now i'm working with the multitouch with 2 finger at event hold button A + click button B or hold button A + hold button B. but i don't get the idea of how to do it at android, send the event to java with mCommandService(BluetoothCommandService.valueOfButon), read in java that button B had been clicked when button A is hold and execute the value representation with robot.keyPress.

i implement the example from this blog http://luugiathuy.com/2011/02/android-java-bluetooth/ for the bluetooth connection between android and java. And this my onTouch method at android

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.tombolL1:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.aksi_l1;
    break;

    case R.id.tombolL2:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.aksi_l2;
    break;

    case R.id.tombolR1:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.aksi_r1;
    break;

    case R.id.tombolR2:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.aksi_r2;
    break;

    case R.id.tombolAtas:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.arah_atas;
    break;

    case R.id.tombolBawah:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.arah_bawah;
    break;

    case R.id.tombolKiri:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.arah_kiri;
    break;

    case R.id.tombolKanan:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.arah_kanan;
    break;

    case R.id.tombolSegitiga:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.aksi_segitiga;
    break;

    case R.id.tombolBulat:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.aksi_bulat;
    break;

    case R.id.tombolSilang:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.aksi_silang;
    break;

    case R.id.tombolKotak:
        cmd = BluetoothCommandService.aksi_kotak;
    break;

}

switch(action){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        handler1.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);
        handler1.postAtTime(mUpdateTask, 200);
    break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        handler1.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTask);
    break;
}
return false;
}

private Runnable mUpdateTask = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        mCommandService.write(cmd);
        handler1.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100);
        //handler1.postAtTime(this, 200);
    }
};
```

and this processCommand method in java

```
private void processCommand(int command) {
    try {
        Robot robot = new Robot();
        int key = 0;
        switch(command){
            case arah_atas:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_UP;
            break;
            case arah_bawah:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_DOWN;
            break;
            case arah_kiri:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_LEFT;
            break;
            case arah_kanan:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT;
            break;
            case aksi_segitiga:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_A;
            break;
            case aksi_bulat:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_X;
            break;
            case aksi_silang:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_Z;
            break;
            case aksi_kotak:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_S;
            break;
            case aksi_l1:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_Q;
            break;
            case aksi_l2:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_W;
            break;
            case aksi_r1:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_R;
            break;
            case aksi_r2:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_E;
            break;
            case aksi_select:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_SPACE;
            break;
            case aksi_start:
                key = KeyEvent.VK_M;
            break;
        }

        robot.keyPress(key);
        Thread.sleep(50);
        robot.keyRelease(key);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

please, let me know how can i do for what i needed?

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has dabbled with multitouch in Android, I would recommend utilizing this [this](http://code.google.com/p/android-multitouch-controller/) library. It abstracts the headache of dealing with the nitty gritty of multitouch. You can scale, rotate, etc. It offers support for phones where multitouch is buggy and has a few demo projects. Moreover (and I've done this before), you can extract transformation matrices and store this information in your database, and later reapply it to your graphics so that they are initialized properly.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer.
but i think, that can't be use at my application and actually, that wasn't the answer i was looking for. maybe, i'll use that later in my other project :)